# Proving that continuity at each entry of matrix implies invertibility

Tags: real-analysis, multivariable-calculus

Suppose $X\subseteq\mathbb{R}^n$ and $\mathbf{d}\in X^\circ$. For every $i,j\in\{1,\ldots,m\}$ assume $a_{ij}:X\to\mathbb{R}$ is continuous at $\mathbf{d}$.

Define the map $T: X\rightarrow \text M_{m\times m}(\mathbb R)$ by

$T(\mathbf{x})=[a_{ij}(\mathbf{x})]_{i,j=1}^m.$

I want to show that if $T(\mathbf{d})=I_m$, then there is some $r>0$ so that $T(\mathbf{x})$ is invertible for any $\mathbf{x}\in B_r(\mathbf{d})$.

To apply the inverse function theorem (according to my version) and thus get the result, I need to show that $T$ is $C^1$ on a neighborhood of $\mathbf c$ and that the Jacobian matrix of $T$ at $\mathbf c$ is invertible. I can show that $T$ is continuous but I'm not able to show that the partial derivatives of $T$ are continuous.

I also don't quite see where the hypothesis that $T(\mathbf{d})=I_m$ comes in. Is this to show that the Jacobian is invertible?

I'd really appreciate some help.

Comment: You don't know $T$ is differentiable (or even that the dimensions match), so I think the IFT is the wrong tool for the job. Think about the definition of continuity - you just need to prove a simple topological property of the set of invertible matrices.

Comment: @AnthonyCarapetis I will know that $T$ is differentiable once I prove it's $C^1$.

Comment: There are plenty of $a_{ij}$ fitting your assumptions that are not differentiable, and $T$ cannot be differentiable unless each $a_{ij}$ is.

Comment: @AnthonyCarapetis Yeah, I see. I'm not sure how to approach it topologically, however.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hint:

The determinant $\det T(x) = \sum_{(j_1, \ldots , j_m)} \sigma(j_1, \ldots,j_m)a_{1j_1}(x) \cdots a_{mj_m}(x)$, where the sum is taken over all permutations of $(1,\ldots,m)$, is a composition of a continuous function and the continuous components. Hence $x \mapsto \det T(x)$ is continuous.

Note that $\det T(d) = 1$ and a matrix is invertible if the determinant is not zero.

Comment: I'm sure you know that a function $f$ that is continuous at $d$ and where $f(d) \neq 0$ is non-zero in a neighborhood of $d$.

Comment: Yes, but I still can't see a solution.

Comment: A matrix is invertible if and only if the determinant is non-zero.  The determinant is just a sum of products of components -- hence, a continuous function of the components. If the components are themselves continuous functions on $X^0$, then the function $x \mapsto \det T(x)$ is continuous on $X^0$.   So if $\det T(d) = 1 \neq 0$ then there is some open ball $B_r(d)$ such that $\det T(x) \neq 0$ for all $x \in B_r(d)$.

Comment: We are just stringing together some basic results of multivariable calculus and one concept from linear algebra.